# couchbase sync not connecting

Tags: angularjs, synchronization, couchbase

I'm working on a angularjs/electron project, and we're utilizing pouchdb noSQL. I'm currently trying to sync the pouchdb to my couchbase server, but when I do i'm receiving this error

> FATAL: Failed to start HTTP server on 127.0.0.1:4985: listen tcp 127.0.0.1:4985: bind: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. -- rest.(*ServerConfig).Serve() at config.go:705

I've already checked my ports, and there's only one instance of my sync port active. So, you can understand why I'm a bit puzzled. If you can offer any suggestions, I'd be very appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. When installing couchbase sync gateway, it comes in as a service. Make sure the service isn't active, when you run it from console.